# Why the "linenos" option fails to add the line number in Jekyll?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, jekyll, line-numbers

I am using jekyll to generate my website.  I want to add a line number column to my code block.  I searched google, and everyone told me to add a "linenos" option to the hightlight tag, but i doesn't work in my case:

```
{% highlight ruby linenos %}
def foo():
puts 'foo'
end
{% endhighlight %}
```

The highlight is working well, but the line numbers....

Could you help me with this?  If you want to see the source css/html files, hit [here](https://github.com/winnieliu/winnieliu-winnieliu.github.com).

Thanks!

Further checking:

the html generated for this section is :

```
<div class="highlight"><pre><code class="ruby">
    <span class="k">def</span> <span class="nf">foo</span><span class="p">():</span>
    <span class="nb">puts</span> 
    <span class="s1">&#39;foo&#39;</span>
    <span class="k">end</span>
</code></pre></div>
```

Comment: Line numbering is usually added via the CSS style, e.g. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.css.  Not sure why the "lineno" class isn't being added to your HTML by Jekyll though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cloned your repo, generated the site, and check it out in the browser. **Everything looks fine.** (I like your layout!) That indicates to me that there's something funky in your setup. Is the code highlighting working for you? If not, you may not have Pygments set up correctly.

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
sudo easy_install Pygments
```

To generate the css:

```
pygmentize -S default -f html > default.css
```

Make sure you have `pygments: true` in your _config.yml.

Make sure to place this stylesheet appropriately and include it in your default.html.

I see that you already have this stylesheet included in your page and your _config.yml seems fine, but for anybody else needing this answer, there it is.

If you generate the site with `jekyll --no-auto` do you see any errors in the output?

Let me know, and I'll be glad to try and help further. :)

---

**Update**: This is the HTML that's generated for me for the highlight test blog post you have.

```
<div class="highlight"><pre><code class="c"><span class="lineno">1</span> <span class="cp">#include &lt;stdio.h&gt;</span>
<span class="lineno">2</span> 
<span class="lineno">3</span> <span class="kt">int</span> <span class="nf">main</span><span class="p">()</span>
<span class="lineno">4</span> <span class="p">{</span>
<span class="lineno">5</span>   <span class="n">printf</span><span class="p">(</span><span class="s">&quot;Hello World!</span><span class="se">\n</span><span class="s">&quot;</span><span class="p">);</span>
<span class="lineno">6</span>   <span class="k">return</span> <span class="mi">0</span><span class="p">;</span>
<span class="lineno">7</span> <span class="p">}</span>
</code></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  I use `jekyll --no-auto`, but no errors prompted.  I asked my friend to generate my site on his computer, and the line number appears, so it's the setup problem.  However, I reinstall pygments, and the line number problem still exist; I even installed a virtual machine (ubuntu 12.04 LTS), and setuped jekyll.  Unfortunately, it fails to generate the line numbers either.

Comment: I edited my answer with the output of the highlight test. Does your output agree? What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: I checked the html in _site, of course, no line numbers, no such things as class="lineno".  I use chromium (it's not the problems of my browser). Thanks.

Comment: If you could update your question with the full output for that section, that would be really helpful.

Comment: I have updated it.  Thanks for your help. (But I don't have much hope for this now.)

Comment: From the looks of it, you've made some destructive changes to the setup so not much is generating anymore. If you're still playing around with the site, I one last thing I would try is putting four or eight spaces in front of the lines inside the highlight tags. That's how regular markdown is supposed to handle code blocks. You could also try debugging using [plugin](https://github.com/plusjade/jekyll-bootstrap/blob/master/_plugins/debug.rb). Like I mentioned, it was all working for me, so it appears to be a setup issue. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I was just experiencing the same issue with pygments and jekyll. My markdown looked as

```
{% highlight c# linenos %}

    //my code

{% endhighlight %}
```

and the resulting generated HTML

```
<div class="highlight">
    <pre>
        <code class="c">
            ...
        </code>
    </pre>
</div>
```

The highlighting was somehow odd and no line numbers have been added. Ultimately the problem was that Pygments apparently didn't recognize "c#" as a valid language, but instead I had to add "csharp".

(just in case someone else has this issue when setting it up)

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing. Although line number were showing the css wasn't being beautiful. The main reason was that bootstrap was conflicting with my style.css. Adding the following to the style.css resolved it.

```
.highlight pre {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: transparent;
    color: inherit;
}
```